Getting AccessToken to attach http request in a delegatinghandler to use in IHttpClientFactory In blazor serverside interactive
Im trying to write a blazor app in dotnet 8 that only uses server side interactive rendering. I want to authenticate against Azure tenant. I have the login working correctly, Im just having a hard time figuring out how to attach the correct authorization token to an http client that is making requests to a different dotnet api that is also authenticated against tenant. It understand that the scope that delegating handlers use is different than that of the signalR circuit that is instantiaded when a client accesses the site. I found this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-9.0#access-server-side-blazor-services-from-a-different-di-scope that describes how to get the authentication state from the circuit. Im just having a hard time figuring out how to ge the access token from this.
using LogisticsTruckScales.BlazorServer.Components;
using LogisticsTruckScales.BlazorServer.Services.Secuirty;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using MudBlazor.Services;
using System.Security.Claims;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddMudServices();
builder.Services.AddScoped<CircuitServicesAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<CircuitHandler, ServicesAccessorCircuitHandler>();
// Add services to the container
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();


builder.Services.AddScoped<ScaleTransactionManagerAuthorizationHandler>();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ScaleTransactionManager", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["ScaleTransactionManager:BaseUrl"]);
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<ScaleTransactionManagerAuthorizationHandler>();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi()
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();

app.Run();


using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Security.Claims;
using static System.Formats.Asn1.AsnWriter;

namespace LogisticsTruckScales.BlazorServer.Services.Secuirty
{
    public class ScaleTransactionManagerAuthorizationHandler : DelegatingHandler
    {
        private readonly CircuitServicesAccessor circuitServicesAccessor;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ScaleTransactionManagerAuthorizationHandler(CircuitServicesAccessor circuitServicesAccessor, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            this.circuitServicesAccessor = circuitServicesAccessor;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var authStateProvider = circuitServicesAccessor.Services
          .GetRequiredService<AuthenticationStateProvider>();
            var authState = await authStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
          
            //I have the auth state here. I want to pass the access token to the request.

            // Attach the token to the request
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }
    }
}

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits;

namespace LogisticsTruckScales.BlazorServer.Services.Secuirty
{
    public class CircuitServicesAccessor
    {
        static readonly AsyncLocal<IServiceProvider> blazorServices = new();

        public IServiceProvider? Services
        {
            get => blazorServices.Value;
            set => blazorServices.Value = value;
        }
    }

    public class ServicesAccessorCircuitHandler(
        IServiceProvider services, CircuitServicesAccessor servicesAccessor)
        : CircuitHandler
    {
        public override Func<CircuitInboundActivityContext, Task> CreateInboundActivityHandler(
            Func<CircuitInboundActivityContext, Task> next) =>
                async context =>
                {
                    servicesAccessor.Services = services;
                    await next(context);
                    servicesAccessor.Services = null;
                };
    }

    public static class CircuitServicesServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddCircuitServicesAccessor(
            this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<CircuitServicesAccessor>();
            services.AddScoped<CircuitHandler, ServicesAccessorCircuitHandler>();

            return services;
        }
    }
}

I know I cant use ITokenAquistion directly in my handler, Ive tried this and I get (MsalUiRequiredException: No account or login hint was passed to the AcquireTokenSilent call)
